# How to set HTML in v-radio label

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I've checked the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selection-controls#api) for `v-radio` components but didn't found a way to set the `label` with HTML in it. Does anyone know if there is a way to do so?

```
<v-radio  label="Some <b>text</b>" value="some-value"></v-radio>
```

Comment: As it accepts only string, I doubt. Why don't you just use CSS to stle the label (I see you used `<b>` )?

Comment: @Vucko css won't help much as I need only one word bold something like 'Show users that are **not** something'.

Comment: @ulou I've tried it but it is also parsing the html tags like a stirngs.

Comment: @ale Yeah because type of `label` property is a `String` and you cannot change this, unless you fork a library. This is just a radio button, you can always write your own one.

Comment: @ulou Incorrect! It's possible via slot, see the answer!

Comment: @Vucko Also, see above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a `label` slot for this.
So do NOT use prop if you need html label.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BqrvGp)

```
<v-radio value="radio-1">
  <template slot="label">
    Vuetify is actually&nbsp;<b>Awesome</b> 
  </template>
</v-radio>
```